# ¿Las preguntas en modo afirmación llevan interrogación? ¿Y tilde?

Tags: acentuación, adverbios, preguntas

El ejemplo más claro lo encontramos en blogs de internet.

Podríamos encontrar artículos cuyo título es:

> Cómo vestir este otoño a la moda.
>
> Cómo enamorar a una chica en 10 pasos.

¿Esto sería así correcto? O debería ser:

> ¿Cómo vestir este otoño a la moda?
>
> ¿Cómo enamorar a una chica en 10 pasos?

Es decir, ¿con interrogación o sin ella?

---

Por otro lado, ¿ese `cómo` debería llevar tilde tal como he puesto en los ejemplos o hay que quitarla?

Y si se tratase de una frase compuesta como por ejemplo:

> Qué es la moda y cómo vestir este otoño.

Ese `cómo`, al estar en el interior de la frase, ¿llevaría tilde?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pueden omitirse los signos de interrogación en algunos casos, como enunciados interrogativos independientes que constituyen el título de una obra, un capítulo, o en este caso, el título de un artículo, o también a veces se omiten los signos de interrogación en las interrogativas retóricas, como en las que no se formula una verdadera pregunta, sino que se expresa indirectamente una aseveración. Aun así también es correcto poner interrogaciones en los ejemplos que has dado.

En cuanto a las tildes, en los pronombres, como qué y cómo, debes ponerles siempre tilde si son pronombres interrogativos. En las oraciones interrogativas, como las que has dado, siempre hay algún pronombre interrogativo que llevará tilde.

En la frase compuesta, ya que se compone de dos oraciones interrogativas, tanto el "qué" como el "cómo" llevarán tilde.

Comment: No se trata de que los signos de interrogación _puedan_ omitirse: no son preguntas en sentido estricto, aunque usen adverbio interrogativo (con tilde). _Juan explica cómo perdió peso_ es una afirmación, aunque el interlocutor seguirá sin saber la manera en que lo logró. V. la entrada del DPD sobre [cómo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=NRljHeeb2D6KmUqa9B) y [como](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=s3kpSlOhuD6v706948).

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de Pablo Fergus es buena, pero tengo una observación:

> En cuanto a las tildes, en los pronombres, como qué y cómo, debes ponerles siempre tilde si son pronombres interrogativos. En las oraciones interrogativas, como las que has dado, siempre hay algún pronombre interrogativo que llevará tilde.

Técnicamente correcto, pero prácticamente inservible. ¿Cuándo son pronombres interrogativos? Esa es precisamente la duda.

No sigas ninguna regla inexistente sobre que llevan tilde si van entre signos de interrogación o exclamación, etc. Estos pronombres llevan tilde cuando son tónicos. El *quid* es este: que sean tónicos.

¿Pronuncias igual el primer «qué» y el segundo «que» en...

> ¿Qué quieres? ¿Que te dé más dinero?

? Me imagino que no. El primero lleva tilde porque es tónico. El segundo, no, por ser átono. Por supuesto, porque el primero es pronombre interrogativo y el segundo es conjunción completiva. Pero si estás haciendo esta pregunta es porque esa guía no te vale...

Comment: Según el DPD, la regla de tónico/átono tiene al menos una excepción: Como _"se hace tónico, aunque sigue escribiéndose sin tilde, cuando se coordina con otro adverbio relativo y no es el último elemento de la coordinación: Me vestiré como y cuando yo quiera."_

Comment: Cierto, y de hecho tiene más excepciones, pero es desde luego lo más fiable en mi opinión (siempre que tengas el oído necesario).